# Find the parent and nearest element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form as

```
<tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="qty"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="price"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="total[]" placeholder="Total"/> </td>
</tr>
```

we can have multiple row with the same as above.

What I need is when the User inputs the `qty` or `price` the row `total` needs to update.

What I tried

```
$('input[name=\'qty[]\']').on('change keyup', function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).parent('tr').find('input[name=\'price[]\']').val();  
});
```

`price` is `undefined`

Or is there an easier way to do it? Please check the [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/epynic/yqe4kwbz/)

**UPDATE :**

`.parent(..)` selects the direct parent of each of the elements in the current set of elements. The first argument filters this set. The direct parent of your input element is the `td` element, not the `tr` element.

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epynic/yqe4kwbz/10/)

Comment: `.parent(..)` selects the parent of each element in the set, **filtered** by the selector. The direct parent is `td`, not `tr`.

Comment: $(this).parent('td').parent('tr')  - works !

Comment: Or just `.parent().parent()`; it's not that you have more than 1 element in that set...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first of, think about making your html as such:

```
<tr>
    <td> <input type="number" name="qty[]" placeholder="qty"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="price"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="number" name="total[]" placeholder="Total"/> </td>
</tr>
```

Also. As far a javascript goes:

```
jQuery(document).on("change ,  keyup" , "input[name='qty[]'] , input[name='price[]']" ,function(){
     var parent_element = jQuery(this).closest("tr");
     var qty = jQuery(parent_element).find("input[name='qty[]']").val();
     var price = jQuery(parent_element).find("input[name='price[]']").val();
     if( qty.trim() != "" && price.trim() != "")
      {
        jQuery(parent_element).find("input[name='total[]']").val( parseFloat(qty) *parseFloat(price) );
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery(parent_element).find("input[name='total[]']").val("");
      }
});
```

EDIT :Better approach, properly taking into account empty fields

Comment: you could consider also adding
jQuery(document).on("change ,  keyup" , "input[name='qty[]'] , input[name='price[]'] , input[name='total[]']" ,function(){
to be sure that if someone tries to alter total by hand, it will instead recalculate it. also you can make total disabled on its html markup (just write disabled inside the <input blablabla disabled > tag

Comment: Your `jQuery(parent_element)`'s can all be replaced with just `parent_element`. `.closest()` *always* returns a jQuery object; you're not gaining anything by using `jQuery()` here.

Comment: well, its a matter of normalization for me, i prefer to always let jQuery decide of what i give it is an element or a selector (this way functions can receive both selectors and elements as input) so i ALWAYS pass it through jQuery

Comment: Fair enough, but surely you only need to do that for inputs you receive from *outside* the function.  In this case, `parent_element` is *always* a jQuery object, so calling `jQuery()` on it does nothing except waste time.  (Anyway, I see that you're still writing `jQuery(...).find(...).val(...)` instead of `jQuery(jQuery(...).find(...)).val(...)`.  If you don't trust `.closest()` to always return a jQuery object, why would you trust `.find()` to do so?)

Comment: It is not a matter of closest, that i trust, but as a rule i do not trust a variable to contain an element versus a selector, it does not matter if i just put it there on the line above, 2 years from now and a lot of changes latter i will be glad i did not trust that variable all that time ago. As i said it is just a matter of normalization for me excluding the reason i stated about functions. In term of speed, it is actually about the same, t wont do any more actions to the object compared to calling it directly

Comment: There is no comma between events, `"change ,  keyup"` should be: `"change keyup"` otherwise only `keyup` would be handled here. BTW, what if user pastes some value using mouse? Because you are using input type number in your answer and because `input` event as better support than `type="number"`, you should use instead: `jQuery(document).on("input" , "input[name='qty[]'] , input[name='price[]']", handler);`

Comment: **⇑⇑⇑ EDIT** *as a side note*: because in your case you were setting extra space between `change` and comma, both events `change` and `keyup` were fired, but that's just because how regex used to split events by spaces handles it, that's kind of a bug to handle this kind of typo

Comment: @Elentriel Good point but i'd use `readonly` boolean attribute instead, to let input beeing submitable regarding `form` data/serialization

Answer (score 4):

Just change `parent()` to `parents()`:

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/yqe4kwbz/9/

Citing from https://api.jquery.com/parents/ sbout `parents()`:

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
>   The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 3):

I"m not sure if you're able to change in the HTML code,but if you can i think it will be better to give your `input`s a `class`s like following example :

```
<tr>
    <td> <input class='calculate' type="number" name="qty[]" placeholder="qty"/> </td>
    <td> <input class='calculate' type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="price"/> </td>
    <td> <input class='total' type="number" name="total[]" placeholder="Total"/> </td>
</tr>
```

And use `class` selectors to get your values :

```
$('.calculate']').on('change keyup', function(){
    var qty   = parseFloat( $(this).parents('tr').find('.qte').val() );
    var price = parseFloat( $(this).parents('tr').find('.price').val() );  

    $(this).parents('tr').find('.total').val( qty * price );  
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[name=\'qty[]\']').on('change keyup', function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name=\'price[]\']').val();
});
```

Although this code works, you have to deal with lots of validations.

Answer (score 2):

`.parent(..)` selects the direct parent of each of the elements in the current set of elements. The first argument **filters** this set. The direct parent of your input element is the `td` element, not the `tr` element.

Since you only have 1 element in your set, don't filter at all. Just get the parent twice, so you select the `tr` element.

```
$('input[name=\'qty[]\']').on('change keyup', function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name=\'price[]\']').val();  
});
```